# What's wrong with my regular expression in web input?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to limit a positive integer or 0. So I wrote this code:

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="${po.age}"  
     onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^[1-9]\d*|0]/g,'')" 
     style="ime-mode:disabled;" onpaste="return false;"
    />
```

But I find that I can only input 1-9. If I input 0, it will be removed. How to fix it?

Comment: I think you wanted to write `value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')`

Comment: If I write according to your way,it can be 00000.In my way,I want to only one 0

Comment: @Tushar,in your way,I can not input 100.It alway change to 10

Comment: Because you need to add `^` - `.replace(/^0+/, '0')`. And if you want to make sure you only contract `0`s if you have a whole string consisting of zeros, use `.replace(/^0+$/, '0')`

Comment: Why don't you use an input type = number ?

Comment: @Thomas,Because I  do not want  the negative integer;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a input of type `number` and set a `min` value to 0:

```html
Try me:
  <input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: I have write this  at first  like  step="1"  ,but I find that can not stop user input like 0.002

Comment: @flower and this will make the form invalid, that's what you want, don't you?

Comment: Yes,and I also do not want the decimal number.

Comment: @flower the user will not be able to post the form since it's invalid, you'll only have to deal with positive integer when the post occurs

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="${po.age}" onkeyup="value = value.replace(/[a-z]|-/gi, ''); value = parseInt(value.match(/\d+|\./gi).join('')) || '';" style="ime-mode:disabled;" onpaste="return false;"
/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vamj5w0/

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can write the regular expression like this, if your need is any digit followed by a zero

/[1-9]\d*[0]{1}/

Comment: This won't allow `0`

Comment: Why it won't allow zero? Please advice me @ThomasAyoub

Comment: In fact it can allow almost anything that contains 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 or 90 in it. It depends how you insert it in the code

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your code `value=value.replace(/[^[1-9]\d*|0]/g,'')` to `value=value.replace(/[^[0-9]\d*/g,'')`
so it will looks like

```html
<input type="text" name="age" id="age"  onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^[0-9]\d*/g,'')" style="ime-mode:disabled;" onpaste="return false;" />
```

Alternative you can try this

```html
<input name="number" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this :

```
value=isNaN(parseInt(value,10))?"":parseInt(value,10)<0?"":parseInt(value,10)
```